# Is there a meaning for the link colors in the user profile reputation tab?

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page

I'm just curious but is there a reason for the different black and blue colored links in the reputation tab on the user profile page? This is what my page looks like:

[image: Reputation tab screenshot]

I'm guessing answer links are black and question links are blue but why is the last link from 2 days ago is a lighter blue and the last link from yesterday a darker blue?

Comment: Because you haven't clicked on that link (visited that page) by now in your browser or cleared the browser history from that event.

Comment: Click on the second link, reload the rep page and see..

Comment: How odd. I did think of that but I could swear I tested it and didn't see the color change. Now I've tried it (again?) and of course you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blue colored links: links going to questions
Black colored links: links going to answers

If a link to a question is light blue, then you haven't yet visited that question. If it is dark blue, then you have visited it.

A link to an answer is always black, it doesn't matter whether it's visited or not.

Comment: What? No. Visited vs Not Visited (as far as browser history is concerned)

Comment: @Oded: Dukeling is right.

Comment: @Dukeling: light-blue is a not visited question: when an answer isn't visited, it is still black.

Comment: @Dukeling: Done.